# Trouble printing a DIctionnary because of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble printing a dictionary that contains tuple keys.
ex:

```
dictio = {(2, 3): red,{(3, 4): blue}
```

I am trying to print:

```
2,3,red
3,4,blue
```

cant seem to get it cleaned up in this order

Comment: actually each key value pair on a separate line

Comment: Please update the correct input dictionary.  Is `red` and `blue` are variable or string? Also, there is extra `{` after `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dictionary is syntactically wrong. I believe this is:

```
dictio = {(2, 3): 'red', (3, 4): 'blue'}
```

Now, to get your desired output:

```
for k, v in dictio.items():
    print(*k, v, sep=', ')

# 2, 3, red
# 3, 4, blue
```

Comment: Yes i forgot add the commas for the 'str'  in this forum but not in my code.

Comment: It works Thanks, i made this way too complicated. What does the * in front of the k do ?

Comment: @RIchardRobitaille, it unpacks tuple, so you get values out of it.